# Cannot post link to fb via app

Tags: facebook, post

If I post a link, it shows up ad posted by me as user. If I post a message, it shows up as posted by the page itself. Why is that? I need the link to show up as posted by the page, not me. The page is mine.

```
$attachment = array(
'access_token' => 'page-token-here', 
'image' => $code->image_urls,
'name' => $code->title,
'link' => $short_url,


);


$page_id="page-id-here";
$res = $facebook->api('/'.$page_id.'/feed','POST',$attachment);
```